# Remove, add, move array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a string that I converted to a multi-dimensional array.

String: `13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2`

I wanna be able to move `27,3,2` to index **1** for example, so it would become:
`13,4,3|27,3,2|65,1,1`

Or remove one of those sections.

I know I can `unset()`, but I'm not sure how to search for an index then move it or unset it.

Comment: can you tell me why you want to move '27,3,2' to index one?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: @Albert Akki  It's for a specific project, but does it really affect the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below one for interchanging the position of last two elements

```
$array = [0 => array(13,4,3), 1=>array(65,1,1), 2 => array(27,3,2)];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($key == count($array)-1) {
        $array[$key] = $array[$key-1]; 
        $array[$key-1] = $value;
    }
}
```

This is for removing the second element.

```
$array = [0 => array(13,4,3), 1=>array(65,1,1), 2 => array(27,3,2)];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if($key == count($array)-1) {
    $array[$key-1] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array using `foreach`

```
   foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

From key you can get the key and can do whatever you like.

Other wise, you can do this if you know the key

```
   echo $array['pass_key_name_here'];
```